# Trouble with 8-bit Carry Lookahead Adder in Verilog

Tags: verilog

[image]
I'm new to Verilog programming. I'm trying to put together an 8-bit Carry Lookahead Adder as a step toward building a 64-bit CLA. Basically, the way I implemented it is I use 2 4-bit CLA "blocks" to create the 8-bit CLA. I'll provide my code, then an explanation of the problem I'm having.

Code below:

```
// 4-BIT CLA CODE
module CLA4Bit(A, B, carryIn, carryOut, PG, GG, Sum);
    input[3:0] A, B;
    input carryIn;
    output carryOut;

    output PG;
    output GG;

    output[3:0] Sum;

    wire[3:0] G, P, C;

    assign G = A & B;
    assign P = A ^ B;
    assign Sum = P ^ C;

    assign C[0] = carryIn;

    assign C[1] = G[0] | (P[0] & C[0]);
    assign C[2] = G[1] | (P[1] & G[0]) | (P[1] & P[0] & C[0]);
    assign C[3] = G[2] | (P[2] & G[1]) | (P[2] & P[1] & G[0]) | (P[2] & P[1] & P[0] & C[0]);

    assign PG = P[3] & P[2] & P[1] & P[0];
    assign GG = G[3] | (P[3] & G[2]) | (P[3] & P[2] & G[1]) | (P[3] & P[2] & P[1] & G[0]);
endmodule

// 8-BIT CLA CODE BELOW
module CLA8Bit(A, B, carryIn, carryOut, Sum);

    // 8-bit wire for the inputs A and B
    input[7:0] A, B;

    // Wire for the ORIGINAL carry-in
    input carryIn;

    // Wire for the carryOut
    output carryOut;

    // Wire that carries the Sum of this CLA
    output[7:0] Sum;

    // Wires for the propagate of the first 4-bit block (p3)
    // and the second (p7)
    wire p3, p7;

    // Wires for the generate of the first 4-bit block (g3)
    // and the second (g7)
    wire g3, g7;

    // Wires for the carry of the first block (c3) and the
    // second (c7)
    wire c3, c7;

    // The two 4-bit CLA blocks that make up the 8-bit CLA

    CLA4Bit block1(A[3:0], B[3:0], carryIn, c3, p3, g3, Sum[3:0]);

    CLA4Bit block2(A[7:4], B[7:4], c3, c7, p7, g7, Sum[7:4]);
endmodule
```

I wrote a basic testbench to test my code:

```
module CLA_TB();

// TEST THE 8-BIT CLA

    // Inputs
    reg[7:0] A;
    reg[7:0] B;
    reg carryIn;

    // Outputs
    wire carryOut;
    wire[7:0] Sum;
    wire PG;
    wire GG;

    // Instantiate the 8-bit CLA
    CLA8Bit CLA8BitDUT (
    .A(A),
    .B(B),
    .carryIn(carryIn),
    .carryOut(carryOut),
    .Sum(Sum)
    );

    // Initialize the testbench signals
    initial
        begin

        // Start with the carryIn set to 0
        assign carryIn = 0;

        // The standard first test. Set
        // A = b0000 0001 and B = b0000 0001
        // Answer should be Sum = b0000 0010
        assign A = 8'b00000001;
        assign B = 8'b00000001;

        #20

        // Next, set A = b0001 1011 and
        // B = b1101 0111. Answer should
        // be Sum = b1111 0010 = hF2.
        assign A = 8'b00011011;
        assign B = 8'b11010111;

        #20

        // Finally, try setting the carryIn
        // to 1 and then test A = b0111 1011
        // and B = b1101 0011. Answer should be
        // Sum = 0100 1111 w/ overflow carry
        assign carryIn = 1'b1;
        assign A = 8'b01111011;
        assign B = 8'b11010011;

        #20

        $finish;

        end

endmodule
```

So the problem is, in my simulations of the testbench (I use ModelSim), the first 4 bits of the Sum (which correspond to the first 4-bit CLA instance in the 8-bit CLA module) are given as X in the Wave page. The second 4 bits add just fine, though.

After doing some research, I found out that X's are displayed in Verilog when a wire has more than one driver (source of the signal?). However, I don't see any place where I send more than one signal to my first 4-Bit CLA instance in the 8-Bit CLA module. Also, if something like that were the cause, then I don't know why it wouldn't happen to the second set of 4 bits as well, since both the 4-bit CLAs are set up very similarly.

Why is this happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> X's are displayed in Verilog when a wire has more than one driver

That is true but it is only part of the story.  There are other cases which produce X'es:

- If a reg is not given a value it will be X.
- If a Z is used in an expression it will produce an X .

**Your waveform has some obvious 'Z' (blue) lines one it.**
If you following the signals back to where they originate: your 4-bit adder never assigns a value to `carryOut`.
Then you make the same error in CLA8Bit.

If you see a 'Z' in a simulation: jump on it! 99.9% of the time you have an wire which has not been given a value!